# Dois bancos de dados em uma aplicação Android

Tags: android, sqlite

Tenho uma aplicação Android e essa trabalha com um banco de dados interno.

Agora estou precisando que essa aplicação trabalhe com 2 bancos de dados internos.

Isso é possível no Android? Algum exemplo que possa ajudar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, só dar um outro nome para seu `DB` em seu `SqliteOpenHelper`. o `SQLite` é um arquivo, então pode haver quantos quiser.

```
package com.example.stackoverflowsandbox;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class SampleHelpeMyDB1 extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myDB1.sqlite";

    public SampleHelpeMyDB1( final Context context, final String name, final CursorFactory factory, final int version ) {
        super( context, SampleHelpeMyDB1.DATABASE_NAME, null, 1 );
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate( final SQLiteDatabase db ) {
        // staff...
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade( final SQLiteDatabase db, final int oldVersion, final int newVersion ) {
        // staff...
    }

}
```

No exemplo acima, estou criando um `DB` chamado `myDB1.sqlite` (nome físico do arquivo do `SQLite`). Como boa prática e facilidade, crie um `SQLiteOpenHelper` para cada banco (arquivo).

Documentação oficial: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html

Tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html#databasetutorial

Comment: Seria legal incluir algum trecho de código para facilitar a compreensão desta funcionalidade.

Comment: Feito @Wakim. Obrigado.